# Is extra ibadah considered bidah?

Tags: bidah

If, for example, I say that I would repeat Subhanallah 10000 times, and Hz. Muhammad (pbuh) didn't advice such thing, is it considered bidah, or should I claim that this ibadah is part of religion in order for it to be bidah?

Answer (score 5):

Given the answer to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1484/18) and the definition of *bid'ah* therein, you would have to claim that there was something special about doing that dhikr 10,000 times or that that specific number has certain virtues, or doing it at a certain time that is not proven from the sunnah, or doing it at a certain place, etc. In general we are encouraged to do dhikr as much as possible, so by itself there is no issue.

And Allah knows better.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a Shia view)

Ibadah is two type. Wajib (obligatory) and Mustahab (liked). the example you said is not obligatory and is it is done without any belief that it is a rule in Islam there is no problem and allowed. but if one say it and believe it is part of Islam and consider it as a rule in Islam then it is Bidah and Haram.

About Wajib Ibadah adding something to them is Bidah.

Also any Zikr has a special spiritual effect on soul of human and it is not recommended use a personal made number of Zikr. it is recommended the numbers based on Hadith only. each Zikr for soul is like a drug for body and one should know spiritual effect of Zikar to can recommend numbers for each Zikr. it is recommended use only Zekr advices by Hadith like: [Tasbih of Bibi Fateme Zehra (a.s)](http://www.duas.org/tasbihzehra.htm)

---

**Reference:**

- [http://makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/websites/farsi/compilation/book.php?bcc=5088&itg=12&bi=87&s=ct)