# What is the Bidaat (Innovation) in Islam? and is there something as Good and Bad bidaat?

Tags: sunnah, fiqh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All bidah are haram or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/all-bidah-are-haram-or-not)

What is the Bidaat (Innovation) in Islam? and is there something as Good and Bad bidaat?

Like the Salat al Taraveeh for which Hazrat Umar ra said that indeed it's a good innovation. So can we classify acts that do not contradict the Shariah and promote good deeds in general as a Good Bidaat or will they just be considered as Bidaat and considered as wrong/bad according to another tradition in which the Prophet Muhammad peace be upon Him said that all biddats are bad?

Comment: I can't comment over there so writing here. How would you accomodate Salat al Taraveeh and other practices that were not introduced during the times of the Prophet nor the Sahaba but are widely practiced across Muslim world in your answer?

Comment: See http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1488

Comment: hmm its there but for some reason it does not comes up when you search. both of these question I tried to look up before

Comment: this question is about definition of Bidat and other is about types of Bidat. so this is not duplicate.